# Conditional order_by statements, Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to incorporate a sorting feature which allows for multiple sorting variables.

I tried to pass .order_by() a function but it keeps failing when I try to include multiple fields.  How do I do this?

```
if request.GET.get('size_sort')=='1':
        def sorts():
            sort='\'bedrooms\',\'bathrooms\''
            return sort
        posts=Post.objects.filter(**keyword_args).order_by(sorts())
```

This returns the traceback:

```
   Invalid order_by arguments: ["'bedrooms','bathrooms'"]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See [Django Book: Chapter 5 Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/):

> > To order by multiple fields (where the second field is used to disambiguate ordering in cases where the first is the same), use multiple arguments:

That is, the correct invocation is:

```
order_by('bedrooms', 'bathrooms')
```

In context, consistent with the original question:

```
def sorts():
    sort = ['bedrooms', 'bathrooms']
    return sort

posts = Post.objects.filter(**keyword_args).order_by(*sorts())
```

Happy coding.

Comment: I didn't give you -1.  either way, I did read the chapter but I couldn't make the call to sorts work.  I assumed it couldn't be a list because I'm noobish about *args.